# Perl Net Telnet to run a command in background and proceed

Tags: perl, telnet

```
my $host = "some ip";
print "telnet into $host";
my $telnet = new Net::Telnet();
$telnet->open(Timeout=>10, Errmode=>'die', Host => $host );
$telnet->waitfor ( "/login:/" );
$telnet->print("user1\n");
$telnet->waitfor ( "/password:/" );
$telnet->print("passwd1\n");
$telnet->cmd("telnet <different ip> <port number> | tee /tmp/log");
print "look at /tmp/log later, proceeding further...";
```

This code creates the /tmp/log file and adds the messages from "telnet  " to file /tmp/log, but its timing out in few seconds, I want it to run *cmd("telnet   | tee /tmp/log");* and proceed further without waiting for a prompt or timeout, so the /tmp/log will keep collecting all the messages printed for me to look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

Net::Telnet only connects you to a remote shell. Executing commands in the background is a feature of the shell, so it does not need to be a feature of Net::Telnet. E.g. you should be able to run a command in the background like `some-command >/tmp/foo &` or a chain of commands with `( some | more | commands ) > /tmp/bar &`. The syntax how you do this depends on the shell you connect to with Net::Telnet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ok, I was not clear, I just want to execute the command and proceed, doesn't matter background or foreground, how can I make the script to proceed to last line of the above shown script?

Comment: Just let the remote shell execute the command in the background, e.g. send something like `( telnet ... | tee /tmp/log ) &`. But again, the exact syntax depends on the shell you connect to. The example should work with sh and bash.